Share the time spent by EF Core migration across independent tests or between same test runs
In my .NET 8 app, migrating my contexts takes 10 seconds on my machine. And since I run hundreds of independent xUnit tests that each have their own databases, the complete suite of tests ends up being too slow, even with parallelism.
I wonder what EF Core does so I can cache it as it's a common step to all my tests.
Any ideas? Maybe a pool of databases that the tests could pick, clear and reuse in parallel?

Is it because of multiple contexts or does only 1 context also take that time? If so, there's probably not much you can do.

you're right, the question is malformed as it takes time even with one context and what I want to do is share whatever between tests whatever it is that EF does so tests are faster when running all together. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Executing integration tests will always take a while when they need to work with a real dataset. For those I would only consider using migrations for one test to assert the overall database structure. For application behaviour tests I would use scripts or database restores with unique DB names for each test fixture. Integration tests would be run as part of CI, or just prior to a release candidate. For unit tests you should be mocking and data access dependencies. Setting up and accessing "real" data is far too slow as unit tests should be run frequently, especially before checking in.

Thank you but it's not a post about integration tests strategy. It's a specific question :-)

We've been doing integration tests for years now in a setup where each test runs in a transaction that is rolled back. There are just a couple of caveats, but for 99% of our code it works great. The very basic setup looks like this.

I ended up having a finite stack of unique database names. I pop a new name when needed and at the end of each test I clear the database to then recycle the database name by pushing it back to the stack.
public class WebApplicationFactoryHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentStack<Guid> Suffixes = new([
        Guid.Parse("7a00615f-c58a-4d4f-a0b7-081a881f58ac"),
        Guid.Parse("2ff693ef-e0ba-4430-bfc1-ac1a9288c99b"),
        Guid.Parse("23ec38d9-7b9c-46b5-9fcb-861f76dd500b"),
        Guid.Parse("7cd51fb0-3a8e-4828-bab1-9d87c2703f1a"),
        ...
    ]);

public static async Task RecycleDb(Guid suffix)
{
    var connectionString = $"Server=localhost;Database={suffix};Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    const string sql = """
                       
                       EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 
                           @command1 = '
                           SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
                        IF ''?'' <> ''[dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]''
                           BEGIN 
                               IF ''?'' = ''[dbo].[AspNetUsers]''
                               BEGIN 
                                   DELETE FROM dbo.AspNetUsers WHERE UserName <> ''SpecificSeededUserName''
                               END
                               ELSE 
                               BEGIN 
                                   DELETE FROM ? 
                               END
                           END'
                       """;
    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql);
    Suffixes.Push(suffix);
}

public static Guid ConfigureDbSync(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var suffix = Suffixes.TryPop(out var result) ? result : throw new Exception("not enough dbs");
    var connectionString = $"Server=localhost;Database={suffix};Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    serviceCollection.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(SqlConnection), _ => new SqlConnection(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
    return suffix;
}

}
